# Finding difficulty in understanding Jmeter functionality

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded one scenario in JMeter. Scenario is, I will login to the application, perform some Registration and logout. when i run/execute this, Login is failing for some reason(i have figured out login failure issue), but my question is, 'Registration' part is executing successfully. whatever 'Success' i am receiving for registration without login, is a correct functionality of the jmeter? i am very new to jmeter, trying to understand how it works.

One more question is, when i execute more than 1 thread(may be 100 or 1000), how does it do the load testing(Does it actually inserts data/values into the database)?

Comment: Here, 'Registration' is not registering for login(sign up). U can consider as creating employee profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below `400` as successful, so i.e. if [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler gets [HTTP Status 200 - OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) - JMeter will "think" that everything is fine.

So if you need to add validation of the response data, i.e. whether it contains `Welcome` text or does not contain `Error` text you can add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to implement pass/fail criteria in your JMeter test.

Similarly you can use [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) to validate whether required data is present in the database, check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) guide to learn how to set up JMeter for DB connectivity and execute queries.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't have any server logic, It just sends requests as defined by user.

The logic is in your server, If it allows registration without login (which seems ok) it will allow it and insert data to your database.

Load test will send similar request in a bulk, so **same** server logic will be executed, and if server won't block it, it will execute same flow as executing 1 thread which will probably include also inserts data into the database

Answer (score -1):

Lakshmikanth,

You need to follow below steps when you are developing new scripts in JMeter:

1. Record your scenario through JMeter proxy
2. Look for the dynamic variables such as session id or token and correlate them
3. Add assertions [JMeter mark the request as pass or fail based on the response code ie. 200, 400 etc so its important that you set the assertion at every step otherwise the JMeter will mark the request as pass if it receive 200 response code similar to your case of registration]
4. Run script single & multiple users with 'Results View Tree' element enabled.

The above steps will help you to make a concrete JMeter scripts.

Comment: Please mark the answer as useful so that others can get the same information